# WPF How to dynamically draw one shape over another using Path and Geometry Group

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to make an application for a homework assignment that adds a RectangleGeometry to the path.data as GeometryGroup Children and then updates the size while I hold down the mouse button and move the mouse and then finalizes it when on mouseup. The problem is that I need the subsequent rectangles to be drawn over top of the preceeding ones. Setting FillRule to nonzero doesn't accomplish this because it still shows the stroke of the underlying rectangles. So how can I accomplish this?

```
    private void path_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        path.Stroke = strokeColor;
        path.Fill = fillColor;
        path.StrokeThickness = thickness;
        p = Mouse.GetPosition((UIElement)sender);
        gg = path.Data as GeometryGroup;                                    

        gg.Children.Add(new RectangleGeometry());

    }

    private void path_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (p == null) return;
        var pp = Mouse.GetPosition((UIElement)sender);
        gg = path.Data as GeometryGroup;
        if (index == 0)
        {
            var pg = gg.Children.Last() as RectangleGeometry;
            pg.Rect = new Rect(p.Value, pp);
        }
        else if(index == 1)
        {
            var pg = gg.Children.Last() as RectangleGeometry;
            pg.RadiusX = pp.X - p.Value.X;
            pg.RadiusY = pp.Y - p.Value.Y;
            pg.Rect = new Rect(p.Value, pp);
        }

    }

    private void Canvas_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        p = null;
    }
```

Comment: "I need the subsequent rectangles to be drawn over top of the preceeding ones". Does that mean you want to replace the last RectangleGeometry by a new one? Like `gg.Children[gg.Children.Count - 1] = new RectangleGeometry()`.

Comment: Draw separate paths. You cannot do what u r trying to do without tricks.